# Filtrar Array e retornar um novo array com os objetos que foram filtrados

Tags: javascript, array

Utilizando `Javascript`, criei uma função o mais simples possível que receba um `_Array_` de objetos `Pessoa` (exemplo: `{name: "Alex", age: 24}`) que retorne um novo `_Array_` somente com os objetos `Pessoa` que possuem idade entre 20 e 30 anos.

```
function Pessoa(nome, idade) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.idade = idade;
}

var alex = new Pessoa("Alex", 20);

if (idade >= 20 && idade <= 30) {

}
```

Acho que está um pouco errado, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Está muito errado. Não vou fazer para você. Mas já sabe o que é *array*? Sabe como criá-lo? Se não sabe esse exercício é avançado demais para você. Sabe como criar função, entende o conceito? Precisa entender bem como essas coisas funcionam antes de fazer isto.

Comment: Você nem mesmo criou um objeto Pessoa. E essa idade dentro desse if, ela nem sequer existe. E se for mesmo um array de objetos, você vai precisar de um foeach pra iterar em cada objeto dos itens do array.

Answer (score 1):

A principio você pode usar a função `filter` para realizar a tarefa, por exemplo;

```
const inventors = [
  { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
  { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', year: 1643, passed: 1727 },
  { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
  { first: 'Marie', last: 'Curie', year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
  { first: 'Johannes', last: 'Kepler', year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
  { first: 'Nicolaus', last: 'Copernicus', year: 1473, passed: 1543 },
  { first: 'Max', last: 'Planck', year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
];

var olders = inventor.filter(function(inventor){
    return inventor.year >= 1500;
});

console.log(older);
```

a variavel `olders` tera um array com os objetos onde a condição foi suprida (year >= 1500)

Na sua função você poderia fazer basicamente.

```
function pessoa(objec) {
    var olders = objec.filter(function(person){
        return person.age >= 20 && <= 30;
    });
    return olders;
}
```